# Firebird error during backup

Tags: firebird

i want to backup firebird database. Below is command that i use to execute the backup.

```
gbak -b -v -user SYSDBA -pass ***** -service localhost:service_mgr -verify -y E:/logs/backup_20111104.log D:\data\campaign.FDB E:/backup/campaign_20111104.fbk -FIX_FSS_METADATA WIN1252 -FIX_FSS_DATA WIN1252
```

However, after 2 hours running, it ends with general error(only in last line). Below is the error.

```
gbak:22068 records written
gbak:    writing data for table AA_1307265720107_842
gbak:19872 records written
gbak:    writing data for table AA_1301338383915_1025
gbak:4 records written
gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors
```

There is 700+ tables in this database. And the database size is 129GB.

I need to get complete stacktrace(if any). Or any idea where to check so i can know the actual error?

Comment: why you use FIX_FSS_METADATA and FIX_FSS_DATA for backup ?

Comment: I thought it help if there is any corruption in my data. Or is it only used during restore? I've run without it also i get the same error, so i guess FIX_FSS_METADATA and FIX_FSS_DATA not help in this case.

Comment: FIX_FSS_METADATA and FIX_FSS_DATA does not fix any corruptions of db structure or data. They are for helping migrate database from Firebird 1.x, 2.0.x to 2.5 version.

Comment: oohh, ok then, im running it again now without those options and already add '-g -ig'.

Comment: I know there for migrating to newer server but there are useful only for restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to repair the database before backup:

```
gfix -mend -full -ignore <db name> -user sysdba -pas masterkey
```

While backing up add two switches **-g -ig** in order to prohibit garbage collection and ignore check sum errors.

Comment: Do i need to close all connection from my application to the database first? because im getting this error:

    "bad parameters on attach or create database
    -secondary server attachments cannot validate databases" 
I've google it and found out that gfix need to have exclusive access to the database.

Comment: Yes. Validation of database requires full control over a file. No other connections are allowed.

Comment: Ok, that case i need to schedule for application downtime with clients later. I'll go for backup with '-g -ig' option first.

Comment: I strongly advice you to create a physical copy of the database and run gfix with -mend against that copy: it can destroy data.

Comment: Also: -mend should be the method of last resort, see the link in my answer below

Comment: There are only two ways, considering database has size of 129 GB: -mend and pump data into new, clear, empty database. Latter will require some 3rd party utility.

Comment: Why do you consider it to be the only resort? And even if it is, you might want to preserve the original database before destroying the data in potentially recoverable errors.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the gfix manual section [Database Validation and Recovery](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gfix/firebird-gfix.html#gfix-dbverify).

> #### Full Validation
>
> By default, validation works at page level. If no need to go deeper and validate at the record level as well, the command to do this is:
>
> ```
> gfix -v[alidate] -full database_name
> ```
>
> using this option will validate, report and update at both page and record level. Any corrupted structures etc will be fixed.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Database Recovery
>
> If the database validation described above produces no output then the database structures can be assumed to be valid. However, in the event that errors are reported, you may have to repair the database before it can be used again.
>
> #### Recover a Corrupt Database
>
> The option required to fix a corrupted database is the gfix -m[end] command. However, it cannot fix all problems and may result in a loss of data. It all depends on the level of corruption detected. The command is:
>
> gfix -m[end] database_name
>
> This causes the corruptions in data records to be ignored. While this sounds like a good thing, it is not. Subsequent database actions (such as taking a backup) will not include the corrupted records, leading to data loss.
>
> ### Important
>
> The best way to avoid data loss is to make sure that you have enough regular backups of your database and to regularly carry out test restorations. There is no point taking backups every night, for example, if they cannot be used when required. Test always and frequently.
>
> Equally, when attempting to recover a potentially corrupted database, always work with a copy of the main database file and never with the original. Using the -mend option can lead to silent deletions of data because gfix doesn't care about internal database constraints like foreign keys etc, the -mend option simply says to gfix "go ahead and clean out anything you don't like".

These are the most important points of this section, but make sure to read the entire chapter. If you need additional support, on the Firebird-support list there are a number of people familiar with the ins and outs of Firebird and how to handle these kinds of errors.